# Change child row color using jquery tablesorter

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

I am using the modified version of the tablesorter jquery add on.

http://www.pengoworks.com/workshop/jquery/tablesorter/tablesorter.htm

I need the collapsed rows to take one coloe and not the parent rows color.

Even when i explicitly set the child color, it is still super-ceded by the parent row color.

How do i break that logic

Comment: Remove `odd` and `even` classes from the injected row and apply your own class with your own `background-color`. However, please post the **relevant** code of your implementation. Add a jsFiddle if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to increase the [CSS specificity](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) of the child rows. The only issue is that the parent row has a cell that row-spans into the child row, so it won't be styled with the rest of the child row.

Try this css (of course use the color you want); [here is a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/tuM8h/):

```
table.tablesorter .expand-child.odd td,
table.tablesorter .expand-child.even td {
    background: #7ff;
}
```

Comment: @Mottie- Thanks a lot, a modification of your change worked for me.

Comment: my modification     .expand-child td{
  background: #B8B8B8;
  }
  
  .expand-child td {
     background: #B8B8B8;
  }

Comment: dude, your demo is very helpfull, tank you