# jquery tablesorter zebra function

Tags: jquery, html-table, tablesorter

I'm working with jquery.tablesorter plugin.
I use sub grid. but the zebra function do this:

```
 $("tr:visible", table.tBodies[0]).each(function(i) {
```

but that put function on every child tr. 
Can you help me to change this line for creating function only on first child of the grid.

```
<table class="GridA">
<tr class="firstchild"><td></td></tr>
<tr class="expand-child"><td>    
    <table class="GridB">
    <tr><td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr class="firstchild"><td></td></tr>
<tr class="expand-child"><td>    
    <table class="GridB">
    <tr><td>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Limit function to first TR ("firstchild")

Comment: maybe I can do something like  "$(this).' > tr'" . I just dont know how for the moment.

Comment: If you are interested, I have a [fork of tablesorter](http://mottie.github.com/tablesorter/docs/) on github which has many improvements. This fix is just one. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:first` selector:

```
$("tr:visible:first", table.tBodies[0])
```

---

```
$("tr:visible:first-child", table.tBodies[0])
```

Comment: finally I was wrong, it's not working, because first get the first element and not the first child.

Comment: I reedit my post. I add another 2 line in the table, showing what the problem is , and that first() dont resolve it.

Comment: @forX Can you elaborate on what should be selected and what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want children of a table, without children-child. I do this $('#' + table.id + " > tbody > tr.dataRow"). working for the moment.

Comment: @forX Something like this? $('#' + table.id + " > tbody").children()?

Comment: You could try `$(table.tBodies[0]).children()` :)

Comment: Or maybe what you really want is to [change the styling of the child row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12485065/change-child-row-color-using-jquery-tablesorter)?